# Can I create multiple Hosted Zone in Amazon Web Services

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, migration

I have more than 1 domains registered with me . Recently signed-up for Amazon Web Services (AWS) .
Can I transfer multiple domains and use "Hosted Zone" services in AWS to host them. In simple ways I have one login of AWS can use it to host more than one domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have unlimited number of domains managed at AWS - I assume you mean using Route 53.